# How to probe rebol layout but just get original spec

Tags: rebol

Let's take:

```
panel1: layout [
    origin 8x8
    h2 "Panel 1"
    field "Field 1"
    field "Field 2"
    button "The Answer" [alert "I know nothing."]
]
```

If I probe panel1 I got a bunch of lines whereas I'd like to get just the original block:

```
[
        origin 8x8
        h2 "Panel 1"
        field "Field 1"
        field "Field 2"
        button "The Answer" [alert "I know nothing."]
    ]
```

How to get just this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use another word to hold the block value:

```
panel1: layout panel-def: [
    origin 8x8
    h2 "Panel 1"
    field "Field 1"
    field "Field 2"
    button "The Answer" [alert "I know nothing."]
]

probe panel-def
```

Because layout function returns a face object with lots of default values. By the way use ? instead of probe because there can be self references in face objects so you'll have a endless probe output.

Comment: So it is obliged to artificially create a panel-def var ?

Comment: yes, the 'LAYOUT function takes a block and returns a nested set of face objects.  the original block is never kept within the layout.  doing so would exacerbate the possibility of memory leaks.

Comment: Well what prevents rebol to keep it in a layout property then. It's quite weird not to be able to get back / keep track of one's input.

Comment: It's not that weird.  In (almost) all languages when you create an object and load into a property the result of 1 + 2 to make 3, they don't let you get [1 + 2] back later.  At least Rebol offers the *option* to store your code "spec" as structure (if you think it will be important later).

Comment: yes, in fact, in just about all apps, the gui specs are already stored in a var and evaluated just before opening the gui.  In most of my apps, on the other hand, the gui spec is not static, but rather constructed in whole or in part at run-time. it would be pretty useless to store it (look at your MVC problem for an example of this).